# How to select only needed fields and values when transform xml to csv

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I'm novice in xml xslt transofrmation. Please, help me with a small sample for understand. I would like:
1) convert xml to csv
2) first string must contains columns names
3) convert only fields: name, state, records\record (get only last record in the list of records)

I also have xslt code, but I can't modify this code for my requirments. Please, help me to modify code.

csv

```
name, state, record 
"Shockwave", "New", "3"
"Other", " Canceled ", "7"
```

xml

```
<projects>
  <project>
   <name>Shockwave</name> 
   <language>Ruby</language> 
   <owner>Brian May</owner> 
   <state>New</state> 
   <startDate>31/10/2008 0:00:00</startDate> 
   <records>
      <record>1</records>
      <record>5</records>
      <record>3</records>
   </records>
  </project>
  <project>
   <name>Other</name> 
   <language>Erlang</language> 
   <owner>Takashi Miike</owner> 
   <state> Canceled </state> 
   <startDate>07/11/2008 0:00:00</startDate> 
   <records>
      <record>5</records>
      <record>6</records>
      <record>7</records>
   </records>
  </project>
</projects>



<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="projects/project" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="project">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove normalize-space() if you want keep white-space at it is --> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(), $quote)" />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This doesn't add up: `<record>1</records>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated that it needs to be. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/projects">
    <xsl:text>name, state, record&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="project">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', name, '&quot;')" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', state, '&quot;')" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', records/record[last()], '&quot;')" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes none of the fields involved contains a quote.

---

### Added:

> Could you modify your xslt file and add function replace single quote
>   two double for value of field "name"?

Add this template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchString">"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="replaceString">""</xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,$searchString)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$searchString)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replaceString"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$searchString)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$searchString"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replaceString" select="$replaceString"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

and change this:

```
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', name, '&quot;')" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
```

to:

```
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Hello.  Gives error:  Not well formed: The end-tag for element type "record" must end with a '>' delimiter.  Also is it possible to define columns name/nodes fields as array for filter?

Comment: The error you cite is an error in your input document.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Your input is not a well-formed XML document (as I already pointed out in a comment on your question) - hence the error. And I am not sure what you mean by "array for filter".

Comment: @michael.hor257k - please, help me. Could you modify your xslt file and add function replace single quote two double for value of field "name"?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Can you possibly use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - if ubuntu 14.04 xsltproc support it than - yes.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev I don't believe it does, so you will have to use a recursive named template. See the edit to my post.